# DataTables: Ignore empty cells when sorting while server side processing is enabled

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using [DataTables](https://datatables.net) jQuery plugin and before I move to server side processing, I was using a custom sorting method to ignore empty cells.

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    'dateNonStandard-asc': function (a, b) {
        var x = Date.parse(a);
        var y = Date.parse(b);
        if (x == y) { return 0; }
        if (isNaN(x) || x < y) { return 1; }
        if (isNaN(y) || x > y) { return -1; }
    },
    'dateNonStandard-desc': function (a, b) {
        var x = Date.parse(a);
        var y = Date.parse(b);
        if (x == y) { return 0; }
        if (isNaN(y) || x < y) { return -1; }
        if (isNaN(x) || x > y) { return 1; }
   }
});
```

Since this is a client method, it's no longer works as I'm using server side processing.

**Complete Code**

**JS**

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    'dateNonStandard-asc': function (a, b) {
        var x = Date.parse(a);
        var y = Date.parse(b);
        if (x == y) { return 0; }
        if (isNaN(x) || x < y) { return 1; }
        if (isNaN(y) || x > y) { return -1; }
    },
    'dateNonStandard-desc': function (a, b) {
        var x = Date.parse(a);
        var y = Date.parse(b);
        if (x == y) { return 0; }
        if (isNaN(y) || x < y) { return -1; }
        if (isNaN(x) || x > y) { return 1; }
   }
});

$('#minio-data').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "/data-src",
    columnDefs: [
       { type: 'dateNonStandard', targets: [-1, -2] }
    ]
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="minio-data" class="table">
     <thead>
          <tr>
               <th width="12%">No.</th>
               <th width="8%">Name</th>
               <th width="20%">Age</th>
               <th width="8%">Gender</th>
               <th width="17%">Joined Date</th>
          </tr>
     </thead>
</table>
```

How can get the same client side sorting behavior when server side processing is enabled?

Regards.

Comment: Datatables passes an [array to server](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) with the columns to which the ordering should be applied and the direction. Use this data to reproduce the sorting on the server side.

Comment: @Shiffty Can you please give post an example?

Comment: Depends on the language you are using on the server side?